# como selecciono un elemento li de una lista con eq() JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hola tengo un problema y es que siempre me sale undefined cuando intento que me aprezca el texto de una lista, a la hora de seleccionarlo he probado ya con la funcion de text() de html() pero no aparece no se por que no me lo encuentra ya he mirado otras funciones pero creo que el problema es que no lo encuentra

```js
var modulo = $('div.module');
var tercero = $('#myList li:eq(2)').html();

function ejercicio1() {
    alert(tercero);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>jQuery Fundamentals :: Home</title>
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="ejercicios.js"></script>

    <style>
        #blog p.excerpt {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body onload="ejercicio1()">
        <ul id="myList">
            <li>List item 1</li>
            <li id="listItem_2" class="bar">List item 2</li>
            <li id="myListItem">List item 3</li>
            <li>List item 4</li>
            <li class="current bar">List item 5</li>
            <li>List item 6</li>
            <li>List item 7</li>
        </ul>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas CSS estándar? Es mejor usar `nth-child(2)`, ¿no?

Comment: Por cierto, ¿estás llamando a la función o tu código crea la función sin llamarla? ¿Ejecutas el código antes o después de haber generado el HTML?

Comment: no puedo usar css por que son ejercicios de jquery jejeje

Comment: Borja, en tu código estás usando un selector CSS (`'#myList li:eq(2)'`). El problema está en que `eq(2)` no forma parte del estándar CSS y requiere de un proceso adicional, sin embargo `nth-child` sí lo es. Por eso jQuery ha decidido dejar de darle soporte, no quieren mantener un código adicional que se puede sustituir por un selector CSS que **SÍ** es estándar.

Comment: ahhh okok pero eso queria hacerlo por jquery por que el profesor nos lo mando asi que si  por mi hay una manera mas facil la voy a usar 100% seguro pero tengo que hacerlo como me dice el Profe  (^_^¿)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema reside en que estás llamando a la función al cargar el body (en el evento `onload`), y la lista no está cargada todavía cuando llamas a dicha función.

Si quisieras ejecutar la función nada más se cargue el contenido, te recomiendo utilizar el evento `DOMContentLoaded` que se ejecuta cuando todo el contenido de la página ha sido cargado y, por tanto, en este caso no te devuelve `undefined`, si no que te devuelve el valor de tu lista.

Además, [**tal y como dice la documentación**](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), la pseudo-clase `:eq` está deprecada por lo que deberías de utilizar el método `.eq` en su lugar de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#myList li').eq(2).html();
```

Tu ejemplo corregido:

```js
var modulo = $('div.module');
var tercero = $('#myList li').eq(2).html();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    ejercicio1();
});

function ejercicio1(){
    console.log(tercero);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>jQuery Fundamentals :: Home</title>
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="ejercicios.js"></script>

    <style>
        #blog p.excerpt {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
        <ul id="myList">
            <li>List item 1</li>
            <li id="listItem_2" class="bar">List item 2</li>
            <li id="myListItem">List item 3</li>
            <li>List item 4</li>
            <li class="current bar">List item 5</li>
            <li>List item 6</li>
            <li>List item 7</li>
        </ul>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por eso era gracias!!! es que al final era una tonteria y lo sabia

Answer (score 4):

Es probable que lo único que te quede sea llamar a la función que has creado o poner el código javascript después del HTML que deseas analizar:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul id="myList">
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li id="listItem_2" class="bar">List item 2</li>
    <li id="myListItem">List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
    <li class="current bar">List item 5</li>
    <li>List item 6</li>
    <li>List item 7</li>
</ul>

<script>
/* El código javascript lo puse DESPUÉS del HTML */
var modulo = $('div.module');
var tercero = $('#myList li:eq(2)').html();

/* Creo la función */
function ejercicio1() {
    alert(tercero);
}
/* Llamo la función */
ejercicio1();
</script>
```

No te recomiendo hacer uso de `<body onload="ejercicio1()">`. En su lugar usa `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ...)`:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
/* Ahora da igual dónde vaya el código javascript */

/* Creo la función */
function ejercicio1() {
    /* Para asegurarnos que el DOM esté generado movemos la búsqueda aquí */
    var modulo = $('div.module');
    var tercero = $('#myList li:eq(2)').html();
    alert(tercero);
}
/* Llamaré a la función cuando se genere el DOM */
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ejercicio1);
</script>

<ul id="myList">
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li id="listItem_2" class="bar">List item 2</li>
    <li id="myListItem">List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
    <li class="current bar">List item 5</li>
    <li>List item 6</li>
    <li>List item 7</li>
</ul>
```